# How to recover the input field using the bookmarkButton with updated input dependent on another input in Shiny?

Tags: r, shiny

I would like to know how to use the `bookmarkButton` to recover an input field when the input field is automatically updated based on another input field. Please see the below code as an example. Please also access this app using this link (https://yuchenw.shinyapps.io/Bookmark_Recovery/).

```
library(shiny)

# Define UI
ui <- function(request){
  fluidPage(

    # A select menu to select the car name
    selectInput(inputId = "Select_Car", label = "Select a car", choices = row.names(mtcars)),

    # A numeric input for mpg
    # It will be automatically updated based on the car selected
    # But users can also provided a numbers
    numericInput(inputId = "MPG", label = "The mpg of the car", value = NA),

    # Bookmark button to save the current state of the app
    bookmarkButton()
  )
} 

# Define Server
server <- function(input, output, session){

  # Reactive function to get the mpg based on car name
  car_mpg <- reactive({
    req(input$Select_Car)
    return(mtcars[row.names(mtcars) %in% input$Select_Car, "mpg"])
  })

  # Update the MPG input
  observeEvent(input$Select_Car, {
    updateNumericInput(session, "MPG", value = car_mpg())
  })
}

# Enable bookmarking
shinyApp(ui, server, enableBookmarking = "url")
```

This example contains two input field. The first one is a `selectInput` that can allow users to select a car name from the `ntcars` dataset. The second one is a `numericInput` that users can specify the `mpg` of the car. If a car name is selected using the `selectInput`, the associated `mpg` value will be automatically updated to the `numericInput`. Finally, there is a `bookmarkButton` to save the input values.

I found that the bookmarkButton cannot recover the values in the `numericInput` if it is a different number than the associated `mpg` of the car name. For example, if I select `Valiant` in the `selectInput`, the `mpg` is `18.1` and it is updated to the `numericInput`. The `bookmarkButton` will generate the below URL for me to recover the app.

[https://yuchenw.shinyapps.io/Bookmark_Recovery/?*inputs*&MPG=18.1&Select_Car=%22Valiant%22&Select_Car-selectized=%22%22](https://yuchenw.shinyapps.io/Bookmark_Recovery/?_inputs_&MPG=18.1&Select_Car=%22Valiant%22&Select_Car-selectized=%22%22)

If you copy and paste the URL to your browser, you will see something similar to the screenshot.

[image]

This works well. But now assuming that I know the `mpg` of `Valiant` has become `20`, not `18.1`, so I changed the `numericInput` value to `20`, such as the below screenshot.

[image]

If I click the `bookmarkButton`, the URL will be this:

[https://yuchenw.shinyapps.io/Bookmark_Recovery/?*inputs*&MPG=20&Select_Car=%22Valiant%22&Select_Car-selectized=%22%22](https://yuchenw.shinyapps.io/Bookmark_Recovery/?_inputs_&MPG=20&Select_Car=%22Valiant%22&Select_Car-selectized=%22%22)

Nevertheless, if we click this URL, the recovered input values for `mpg` is `18.1` not `20`.

I know this is related to the `updateNumericInput` because I ask the app to update the `numericInput` based on the `selectInput`. Is there a way to ask the `bookmarkButton` to recover the `mpg` as `20`, not `18.1`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that the reactive is being run when it is created (i.e. when the event handler is associated). The values are correctly set (by the browser) to whatever you're passing in the URL (notice the bookmark generates the correct URL), but then they're being changed when the handler is executed on creation.

The solution is to pass `ignoreInit=TRUE` to `observeEvent` to have it not run the handler upon creation (thereby keeping your URL-passed values).

```
# ...

server <- function(input, output, session){

    # Reactive function to get the mpg based on car name
    car_mpg <- reactive({
        req(input$Select_Car)
        return(mtcars[row.names(mtcars) %in% input$Select_Car, "mpg"])
    })

    # Update the MPG input
    observeEvent(input$Select_Car, {
        updateNumericInput(session, "MPG", value = car_mpg())
    }, ignoreInit=TRUE) # notice the parameter has been passed here.
}

# ...
```

Comment: Fantastic. I will reward you the bounty when SO allows me to do so.

Comment: Glad to help :)